# How to avoid writing multiple declarations and instead use loops?

Tags: python, arrays, plot

I wanted to know what could happen to 3n+1 equation at every iteration so beside x for input and z for output I wanted also y as iteration. The result a 3dimensional plot but the figure is not clearly to gain information at large values. Most of the output values are small. My final goal is to have a 3dimensional surface something like z = x / y.

I was doing this in python so there is still a little work to do to make for nth iteration my current state is like this

```
a0 = [i for i in range(1, n)]
a1 = foo(a0)
a2 = foo(a1)
a3 = foo(a2)
z = a0 + a1 + a2 + a3
```

I tried three different ways to generalize this but all I ended up was that It work only for step 1 then it changed my desired values or it just repeated the first variable.

The **foo** function is just taking the previous array calculate the 3n+1 formula and returns array as well.

I also will need some help since I am a beginner how could I "smooth" this plot out of many points, where as reference you might see this figure here.

[image]

The most importat part of my code if needed some more information:

```
x = []
y = []
z = []

n = 5001

for iteration in range(20):#this should be equal to number of subarrays summing
    for i in range(1, n):
        x.append(i)
        y.append(iteration)
```

The actual two functions I used are:

```
def collatz(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n//2
    else:
        return 3*n + 1

def an(old_arr):
    return [collatz(i) for i in old_arr]
```

Comment: Can you present a small example of values for x,y,z (the expected output)?

Comment: Sure here it is
x = [1,2,3,4,5,   1,2,3,4,5,      1,2,3,4,5,    1,2,3,4,5, ...]
y = [0,0,0,0,0,   1,1,1,1,1,      2,2,2,2,2,    3,3,3,3,3, ...]
z = [1,2,3,4,5,   4,1,10,2,16,  2,4,5,1,8,    1,2,16,4,4,...]

Comment: If I do `an(x)`, i get `z=[4, 1, 10, 2, 4, 1, 10, 2, 4, 1, 10, 2]` when i keep iterations=3 and n=5 just to replicate the values you showed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function which has for loop nested in a while loop and when the condition is full filled it returns the axis you provided it.

```
def cal_zxy(n, axis, condition): # axis is z, x or y and condition is when you want to stop the while loop

    while condition :
        a = []
        for i in range(1,n):
            a.append(i)
            a = foo(a)
        axis += a
        
        # change condition to stop infinite loop

    return axis
```